# RESTful design for accessing the same resource in different formats from different audiences

Tags: rest

**Use case**

I am building a webshop where people can register/sign in and can purchase (and afterwards manage) their SaaS licenses. For this purpose I created (among others) the following REST endpoints:

```
// Lists all licenses which are linked to this user
r.Get("/users/{userID}/licenses", api.LicenseSvc.HandleGetLicenses())

// List details (such as purchase date, seat information, ...) for a given licenseID
r.Get("/users/{userID}/licenses/{licenseID}", api.LicenseSvc.HandleGetLicense())

// Creates a new license for the signed in user
r.Post("/users/{userID}/licenses", api.LicenseSvc.HandleCreateLicense())

// Each license has a limited number of seats. The license manager can free up seats to make room for others
r.Delete("/users/{userID}/licenses/{licenseID}/seats/{seatID}", api.LicenseSvc.HandleDeleteSeat())
```

The above endpoints are only supposed to be used in the webshop/license management panel. At the same time the same service has to serve endpoints for the SaaS products which actually use the license(s) a user has created/purchased before. This SaaS product needs different endpoints such as:

- An endpoint to check at startup whether a given license is valid at all
- An endpoint which also gets the license by ID (see above), but it should only return a subset of the license resource (e. g. it shouldn't return the date when the license was purchased)

**My question**

Due to the fact that I am building one REST API which is consumed by two different "audiences" (on the one hand the license manager/customer and on the other hand the SaaS software) I feel like I am running into conflicts.

The authentication of both audiences is different, both audiences want to access the same kind of resource (e. g. a license) but the resource "format" (no customer sensitive data for the SaaS requester) should be different depending on the audience.

1. Should this be reflected via different REST URLs or should I handle all that logic inside of my route handlers?
2. Should I even create two different services serving these different audiences? Like one API for the userpanel/license management and one for the SaaS products!?

Comment: hate to be that guy but have you considered using GraphQL? You are describing exactly why it was created (well almost) ...

Comment: To be honest not really. I was aware that GraphQL resolves the overfetching problem, but I haven't dived into authorization. I'll read up on it and see if it makes sense to me. I'd be happy to figure out how one would resolve it in a RESTful way regardless of the outcome.

Comment: Fair. To be honest, I find this question a little bit broad & opinion based for SO but I won't flag it as such. I also don't know what language/framework you are using, thus don't know your capabilities. That being said, my personal opinion is that, having an extra service is an overkill. Services are complicated and that surface should be minimized. You should certainly have different end point for two as that is clearer to the reader. If I was in FP, I would fetch the same schema and have implicit converters remove the sensitive stuff at the controller.

Comment: I guess you could specify the audience in the route - that way your problem would go away probably but then you'll expose two different API endpoints which I'd say makes sense as they point to two different resources which require to be introduced via two different addresses

Comment: I still believe that most people don't understand what REST is and what it's not, which is especially frustrating on a platform dedicated to software developers and engineers. Instead of attempting to really implement a system that is compliant with Fielding's thesis, which would aim for a strong decoupling of clients from servers, all just seem to follow this pseudo-REST-but-truly-WebRPC thing and belief they are doing the right thing. If the Web would work like "our" modern Web-applications, we'd need a new browser per homepage we request, as this is truly what all do with their REST APIs

Answer (score 1):

REST is not very well prepared for these multi-client scenarios. i have seen many REST apis where certain attributes of resources will only be filled under certain circumstances where i find that perfectly fine. however i have also seen many examples of multiple use cases bunched into single resource models where the swagger documentation with its limiting structure terribly fails to communicate the purpose of each field.

so: as long as the use cases do not differ too much, i would try to keep the count of endpoints low.

tip: have a look at GraphQL, it is much better equipped for handling such cases with querying only for certain sets or even only asking for certain fields, putting the client in control. however using GraphQL as the primary interface is still somewhat exotic and comes with quite substantial initial cost compared to the plentiful REST infrastructure available. still worth it.